# Locus of points and angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The angle bisector at A of triangle ABC cuts BC at L. If C describes a circle whose center is A and B remains fixed, what is the locus of the points L?

I tried some sketches and some geogebra but I don't know how to catch and land my idea. 
Any hint?

Thank you !!

Comment: As $AB$ is fixed and $AC=R$ doesn't change too, you can use $\frac{BL}{LC}=\frac{BA}{AC}$ thus it will be circle, homothetical to the given. Can you find homothety coefficient and center?

Comment: Oh, I can see it, but it is hard to me to find that, can you give me a formula or hint please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $AB$ is fixed and $AC=R$ doesn't change too, we can use $\frac{BL}{LC}=\frac{BA}{AC}$ thus it will be circle, homothetical to the given.
$$\frac{BC}{BL}=\frac{LC}{BL}+1=\frac{AC}{BA}+1=\frac{R+AB}{AB},$$ $$\frac{BL}{BC}=\frac{AB}{R+AB},$$ $$BL=\frac{AB}{R+AB}BC,$$
so the center of homothety is $B$ and the coefficient is $\frac{AB}{R+AB}$.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !!